Is Dawn and Sunshine the same power or is it different?
A while ago, I read or saw in either Youtube or a webpage that Dawn and Sunshine where the same power, the grace given to Escanor which formerly had Mael and which was given and create by the Supreme Deity to Mael. But now in the Nanatsu no Taizai wikia they are implying they are not, even though they say they are very similar.
Is Dawn and Sunshine the same power or is it different?
